# Meaning of different tokens in a font config string

Tags: x11, configuration, fonts

I have seen lines like the one below, in a number of config files (`xmobar` has one of these and `dmenu` too has this)

```
'-*-fixed-*-*-*-*-18-*-*-*-*-*-*-*'
```

1. What is the meaning of each token which is separated by a hyphen (`-`)?
2. Where can I see a list of fonts which I can use in these configs?

There is another variation of this with obvious placeholders. Where can I see a list of fonts for this? (I understand that `xft` fonts are different)

```
xft:Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:size=10:antialias=true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`xfontsel`](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xfontsel.1.html) will allow you to view, select and adjust all of these fields:

[image: xfontsel in action...]

You can also use the command [`xlsfonts`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xlsfonts.1.html) to see a list of installed fonts. This will list *all* fonts, so you may want to pipe it through `grep` to view required subsets, eg,: `xlsfonts | grep droid`

Similarly, [`fc-list`](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X11R7.0/doc/html/fc-list.1.html) will display a list of all installed fonts.

You can read more about the differences between core and Xft fonts here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_X11/Fonts#Core_versus_Xft_fonts

Answer (score 4):

The former is a [X logical font descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_logical_font_description); the linked article describes each field. The `xfontsel` tool can help you create a XLFD interactively.

The latter is a [Xft font name](http://keithp.com/~keithp/render/Xft.tutorial). While there are API calls for enumerating the various fonts, I don't know of any tool that exposes it since most have changed over to [Fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig) already.